# Display the map to fit all the screen of the iPhone

Tags: ios, android-mapview

i do this in order to display the map :

```
[self setMapView:[[[RMMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400, 200)]autorelease]];
```

the 400 and 200 values are for width and height, i need to change it to fit all the screen, thanx in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean "fit"?  What is RMMapView?  What happens right now when you do the above?  Why did you choose 400 x 200?

Comment: Hi Anna, well, RMMapView is the map from the Route-Me framework, never mind, it comports exactly as a map view, i need that it fit all the screen but i don't know exactly what is the exact dimensions of the screen so what to put in place of 400 and 200

Comment: Have you tried self.view.bounds instead of the specific cgrect?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably google the dimensions of an iPhone screen, but here they are: 480x320pt including status bar.  The status bar is 20pt.

You can also ask [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow for its frame.